# Strange output with Array.filter() method

Tags: javascript

In the code below I expected the result of `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);` would be `[1,1]`.

But the result pops out to be `[1,2,3,1,2,3]`.

Where am I going wrong?

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  function hlp(x) {
    for(var i=1; i<arguments.length ; i++) {
      if(x == arguments[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return arr.filter(hlp);
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: `destoryer()` function is only accepting one argument but you have passed three while calling.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia yeah and that one argument accepted is the array, and the latter arguments is passed implicitly to the `arguments` object of the function. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it is, but if you want to use them inside `hlp()`, then you have to pass them again in `hlp()` function. `arguments` array inside `hlp` refers to its own arguments array and not the outer function's

Comment: @abhishekkannojia oh yeah that was overlooked. is there anything else where i was going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ES6 [`rest parameter syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and check if array includes any of those parameters using `include()`

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...rest) {
  function hlp(e) {
    return !rest.includes(e)
  }
  return arr.filter(hlp);
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

If you want to use `for` loop and `arguments` your code should look like this.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var arg = arguments

  function hlp(x) {
    for (var i = 1; i < arg.length; i++) {
      if (x == arg[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return arg[0].filter(hlp);
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: really appreciated. but i haven't yet delve into ES6. and moreover my point was where i was going wrong. someone here let me figured out that i should passed `argument` object inside help too.

Comment: yeah that is much appreciated, sophisticated efficient and clean code

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `destroyer` to only accept one argument, while you're passing in more than one. `arguments` is undefined, and iterating in a function passed to `Array.filter()` isn't a good idea. `Array.filter()` checks every element for you. Not that it would work in your code, but if it would, it would be better to just return `x == arguments[i]` instead of checking whether it's `true` or `false`. If you return `x == arguments[i]` you're actually returning a boolean. An example of that is where I in the code below `return exclude.indexOf(i) == -1;`. Try the following approach instead:

```js
function destroyer(arr, exclude) {
  return arr.filter(function(i) {
    return exclude.indexOf(i) == -1;
  });
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3]));
```

Comment: yeah one argument is being passed via `arr` parameter and that argument being the first one. the latter arguments is being passed via `arguments` object. i should have passed the `arguments` object inside `hlp` function too. this was overlooked by me and brought to the spotlight by one user. Btw you told i did plenty of wrong. can you please let me know where else i was going wrong except the point i mentioned here?

Comment: @Neel Updated with some more

Answer (score 0):

Solved in two ways:

1st:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  function hlp(x) {
    for(var i=1; i<destroyer.arguments.length ; i++) {
      if(x == destroyer.arguments[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return arr.filter(hlp);
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

2nd

Look to the solution posted by @Nenad Vracar